# Simple C code not working

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have written a simple code to check whether a given character is present in the string entered by the user but it doesn't seem to work.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char a[20],b;
    int i,p=0,n;
    printf("Enter the string-");
    scanf("%s",a);
    printf("\nEnter the character-");
    scanf("%c",&b);
    n=strlen(a);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==b)
        {
            printf("\ncharacter is present in string\n");
            p=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(p==0)
        printf("\nchracter is not present in string\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is this: http://i58.tinypic.com/2gvnedt.png

I do not see what is wrong with the code. If I replace "scanf("%s",a);" with "gets(a);" it works fine. Why?

Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: As as side note, don't use `gets` it has been removed from the C standard. Use `fgets` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a space character in:

```
 scanf(" %c",&b);
        ^
```

To consume the trailing `\n` character that is left in stdin after the first `scanf`.

So a `\n` is left in the standard input from which `scanf` is reading. So when a new `scanf` is met it scans the old `\n` character.

To neutralize that effect I put a space character in `scanf` i.e. I am telling it to expect to read a `\n` or space or `\t` and then to read a `%c`.

Comment: Thanks Igor! That fixes the problem but can you please explain a little more on how the space character "consumes" the trailing `\n`. I do see that if I don't put a space, the `\n` is automatically parsed into b.

Comment: @PranavArora See the manpage for scanf. Format strings are made up of a number of directives. A whitespace character in the format `matches any amount of white space, including none, in the input.`  http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf